Parallax elements - in x direction only with javascript

I'm trying to recreate this parallax feature where the x position changes between two layers depending on mouse movement.
I unsure which element, if its the section the mouse should be tracking and what formula is used to modify the position of the elements as well as give it an easing effect so it doesnt just stop suddenly when the mouse stops.
mousemove on the .hero-section
$(".hero-section ").mousemove(function(event) {
  console.log("mousemoveY---", event.clientX, event.clientY);
})



$( document ).ready(function() {


var myElement2= $(".hero-section-text-holder");
var myElement = $(".hero-text-blur");

function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, zPos, el) {
  console.log("test");
  el.style.transform = `translate3d(${xPos}, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg)`;
}


myElement.mousemove(function(event) {
  console.log("mousemoveY---", event.clientX, event.clientY);

  let x = event.clientX;

  var position = {
    left: myElement[0].offsetLeft
  };

  console.log("x", x);

  console.log("position", position);

  let degx = position.left - x;

  console.log("degx", degx);

  setTranslate(-(degx / 20)+"px" , 0, 0, myElement[0]);
  
  
 setTranslate((degx / 10)+"px", 0, 0, myElement2[0]);
});


myElement.mouseleave(function() {
  console.log("mouseleave");
  setTranslate(0, 0, 0, myElement[0]);
  setTranslate(0, 0, 0, myElement2[0]);
});

});
body {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: Manrope, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}


.container {
  padding: 40px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}



.hero-section {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}

.hero-section-text-holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 130vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}


.hero-section-sticky {
    width: 100%;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 50%;
}


.hero-sticky-holder {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}


.hero-text-holder {
    grid-column-gap: 60px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
}

.hero-text-wrapper {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}


.hero-text {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #eec5bd, #f3b1a5 35%, #c6caf6 72%, #dad9e9);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    font-size: 14vw;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.hero-text-blur {
    opacity: .64;
    filter: blur(120px);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #eec5bd, #f3b1a5 35%, #c6caf6 72%, #dad9e9);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    font-size: 14vw;
    font-weight: 800;
    position: absolute;
}


.hero-text._02 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #eec5bd, #f3b1a5 6%, #c6caf6 61%, #dad9e9 72%);
}


.iphone-holder {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 600px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 6%;
}

.iphone-holder{
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    opacity: 1;  
}





.iphone-screen {
    z-index: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 4.1% 4.6%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
}

.iphone-screen-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 0%;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.iphone-image {
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.iphone-drop-shadow {
    width: 120%;
    height: 70%;
    filter: blur(64px);
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="hero-section">
    <div class="hero-section-text-holder" style="will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(-6.72px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;">
      <div class="hero-section-sticky">
        <div class="hero-sticky-holder">
          <div class="hero-text-holder" style="will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(13.44px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;">
            <div class="hero-text-wrapper _01" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d; opacity: 1;">
              <div class="hero-text">Test1</div>
              <div class="hero-text-blur" style="opacity: 0.6; filter: blur(120px); will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(-33.6px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;">Test1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="hero-text-wrapper _02" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d; opacity: 1;">
              <div class="hero-text _02">Test2</div>
              <div class="hero-text-blur" style="opacity: 0.6; filter: blur(120px); will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(-33.6px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;">Test2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="iphone-holder" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d; opacity: 1;"><img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefb47917c0cfa0943fc97_iPhone%2014%20Pro%20%E2%80%93%20Space%20Black.webp" loading="lazy" sizes="(max-width: 767px) 196.6796875px, 295.015625px" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefb47917c0cfa0943fc97_iPhone%2014%20Pro%20%E2%80%93%20Space%20Black-p-500.webp 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefb47917c0cfa0943fc97_iPhone%2014%20Pro%20%E2%80%93%20Space%20Black.webp 800w" alt="" class="iphone-image">
        <div class="iphone-screen"><img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefd2632bfdbf4073fa431_Hero%20Iphone%20Image.webp" loading="lazy" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 80vw, 267.875px" srcset="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefd2632bfdbf4073fa431_Hero%20Iphone%20Image-p-500.webp 500w, https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefd2632bfdbf4073fa431_Hero%20Iphone%20Image.webp 729w" class="iphone-screen-image"></div>
        <div class="iphone-drop-shadow" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>



--- best parallax portion example to date 19th sep


const iphone = document.querySelector('.iphone-holder'),
  backgroundText = document.querySelector('.hero-text-holder')

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  const halfWindow = window.innerWidth/2,
    xVal = e.pageX - halfWindow,
    positionInWindow = (xVal/window.innerWidth),
    pct = 10 * positionInWindow
  
  iphone.style.transform = `translateX(${pct}%)`
  backgroundText.style.transform = `translateX(${-0.3*pct}%)`

})
body {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: Manrope, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}


.container {
  padding: 40px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}



.hero-section {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}

.hero-section-text-holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 130vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}


.hero-section-sticky {
    width: 100%;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 50%;
}


.hero-sticky-holder {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}


.hero-text-holder {
    grid-column-gap: 60px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
}

.hero-text-wrapper {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}


.hero-text {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #eec5bd, #f3b1a5 35%, #c6caf6 72%, #dad9e9);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    font-size: 14vw;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.hero-text-blur {
    opacity: .64;
    filter: blur(120px);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #eec5bd, #f3b1a5 35%, #c6caf6 72%, #dad9e9);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    font-size: 14vw;
    font-weight: 800;
    position: absolute;
}


.hero-text._02 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #eec5bd, #f3b1a5 6%, #c6caf6 61%, #dad9e9 72%);
}


.iphone-holder {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 600px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 6%;
}

.iphone-holder{
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    opacity: 1;  
}





.iphone-screen {
    z-index: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 4.1% 4.6%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
}

.iphone-screen-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 0%;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.iphone-image {
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.iphone-drop-shadow {
    width: 120%;
    height: 70%;
    filter: blur(64px);
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="hero-section">
    <div class="hero-section-text-holder" style="will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(-6.72px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;">
      <div class="hero-section-sticky">
        <div class="hero-sticky-holder">
          <div class="hero-text-holder" style="will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(13.44px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;">
            <div class="hero-text-wrapper _01" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d; opacity: 1;">
              <div class="hero-text">Test1</div>
              <div class="hero-text-blur" style="opacity: 0.6; filter: blur(120px); will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(-33.6px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;">Test1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="hero-text-wrapper _02" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d; opacity: 1;">
              <div class="hero-text _02">Test2</div>
              <div class="hero-text-blur" style="opacity: 0.6; filter: blur(120px); will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(-33.6px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;">Test2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="iphone-holder" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d; opacity: 1;"><img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefb47917c0cfa0943fc97_iPhone%2014%20Pro%20%E2%80%93%20Space%20Black.webp" loading="lazy" sizes="(max-width: 767px) 196.6796875px, 295.015625px" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefb47917c0cfa0943fc97_iPhone%2014%20Pro%20%E2%80%93%20Space%20Black-p-500.webp 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefb47917c0cfa0943fc97_iPhone%2014%20Pro%20%E2%80%93%20Space%20Black.webp 800w" alt="" class="iphone-image">
        <div class="iphone-screen"><img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefd2632bfdbf4073fa431_Hero%20Iphone%20Image.webp" loading="lazy" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 80vw, 267.875px" srcset="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefd2632bfdbf4073fa431_Hero%20Iphone%20Image-p-500.webp 500w, https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefd2632bfdbf4073fa431_Hero%20Iphone%20Image.webp 729w" class="iphone-screen-image"></div>
        <div class="iphone-drop-shadow" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>




added this fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/rp2yfcvz/ -- this handles the parallax

This is a great example of how react overcomplicates things - the full JS necessary to do this is:
const iphone = document.querySelector('.iphone-holder'),
  backgroundText = document.querySelector('.hero-text-holder')

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  const halfWindow = window.innerWidth/2,
    xVal = e.pageX - halfWindow,
    positionInWindow = (xVal/window.innerWidth),
    pct = 10 * positionInWindow
  
  iphone.style.transform = `translateX(${pct}%)`
  backgroundText.style.transform = `translateX(${-1*pct}%)`

})

If you want to mess with the way the parallax renders and the amount that it adjusts by, you can tweak the multipliers. For example if you want the background to shift more or less in relation to the foreground element, you can increase or decrease the -0.3 multiplier


const iphone = document.querySelector('.iphone-holder'),
  backgroundText = document.querySelector('.hero-text-holder')

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  const halfWindow = window.innerWidth/2,
    xVal = e.pageX - halfWindow,
    positionInWindow = (xVal/window.innerWidth),
    pct = 10 * positionInWindow
  
  iphone.style.transform = `translateX(${pct}%)`
  backgroundText.style.transform = `translateX(${-0.3*pct}%)`

})
body {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: Manrope, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}


.container {
  padding: 40px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}



.hero-section {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}

.hero-section-text-holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 130vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}


.hero-section-sticky {
    width: 100%;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 50%;
}


.hero-sticky-holder {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}


.hero-text-holder {
    grid-column-gap: 60px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
}

.hero-text-wrapper {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}


.hero-text {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #eec5bd, #f3b1a5 35%, #c6caf6 72%, #dad9e9);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    font-size: 14vw;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.hero-text-blur {
    opacity: .64;
    filter: blur(120px);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #eec5bd, #f3b1a5 35%, #c6caf6 72%, #dad9e9);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    font-size: 14vw;
    font-weight: 800;
    position: absolute;
}


.hero-text._02 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #eec5bd, #f3b1a5 6%, #c6caf6 61%, #dad9e9 72%);
}


.iphone-holder {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 600px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 6%;
}

.iphone-holder{
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    opacity: 1;  
}





.iphone-screen {
    z-index: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 4.1% 4.6%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
}

.iphone-screen-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 0%;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.iphone-image {
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.iphone-drop-shadow {
    width: 120%;
    height: 70%;
    filter: blur(64px);
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
}
<div class="container">

  <div class="hero-section">
    <div class="hero-section-text-holder" style="will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(-6.72px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;">
      <div class="hero-section-sticky">
        <div class="hero-sticky-holder">
          <div class="hero-text-holder" style="will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(13.44px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;">
            <div class="hero-text-wrapper _01" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d; opacity: 1;">
              <div class="hero-text">Test1</div>
              <div class="hero-text-blur" style="opacity: 0.6; filter: blur(120px); will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(-33.6px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;">Test1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="hero-text-wrapper _02" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d; opacity: 1;">
              <div class="hero-text _02">Test2</div>
              <div class="hero-text-blur" style="opacity: 0.6; filter: blur(120px); will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(-33.6px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;">Test2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="iphone-holder" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d; opacity: 1;"><img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefb47917c0cfa0943fc97_iPhone%2014%20Pro%20%E2%80%93%20Space%20Black.webp" loading="lazy" sizes="(max-width: 767px) 196.6796875px, 295.015625px" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefb47917c0cfa0943fc97_iPhone%2014%20Pro%20%E2%80%93%20Space%20Black-p-500.webp 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefb47917c0cfa0943fc97_iPhone%2014%20Pro%20%E2%80%93%20Space%20Black.webp 800w" alt="" class="iphone-image">
        <div class="iphone-screen"><img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefd2632bfdbf4073fa431_Hero%20Iphone%20Image.webp" loading="lazy" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 80vw, 267.875px" srcset="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefd2632bfdbf4073fa431_Hero%20Iphone%20Image-p-500.webp 500w, https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefd2632bfdbf4073fa431_Hero%20Iphone%20Image.webp 729w" class="iphone-screen-image"></div>
        <div class="iphone-drop-shadow" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>




this looks cleaner and smoother - and its not malfunctioning on the edges -- should we be using refs instead of documentids -- and also does your version load in the text like this -- https://az-black.webflow.io/ - it kind of tiles left first then right

I don't use react, mostly because it's overkill for 90% of projects i've seen it used on. This is just javascript. There's no additional code for tiling either, this is just showing how to achieve the effect in the question

This is the latest version I have - 19th Sep -- but there is a bug in how it loads in - and I think if you go off to the side too much it misses the element and the parallax malfunctions.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/focused-goldwasser-j3t9n8
"use client";

import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Play } from "lucide-react";
import { isMobile } from "react-device-detect";

// Hero Section
const Hero = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const textRef = useRef(null);
  const imagemove = useRef(null);

  //make effects in mobile image & texts ...
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document
      .getElementById("makeEffectInto-left-Text")
      ?.classList.add("makeEffectIntoText");
    document
      .getElementById("makeEffectInto-right-Text")
      ?.classList.add("makeEffectIntoText-2");

    setTimeout(() => {
      let textfontSize = document.getElementById("meedtextone");
      let textfontSize2 = document.getElementById("meedtextone2");
      textfontSize.style.fontSize = "14vw";
      textfontSize2.style.fontSize = "14vw";
      document
        .getElementById("imageId-forRemove-hiddhen")
        ?.classList.remove("hidden");
      document
        .getElementById("imageId-forRemove-hiddhen2")
        ?.classList.remove("hidden");
      document
        .getElementById("hiddenImageComesFromDown")
        ?.classList.add("imageId-forRemove-hiddhenmain");
    }, 1200);
  }, []);

  //for effecting in mobile & background-text in mouse move
  useEffect(() => {
    const container = containerRef.current;
    const text = textRef.current;
    const imageMove = imagemove.current;

    setTimeout(() => {
      function getMouseDirection(e, element) {
        const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = e.clientX - rect.left; // Mouse X relative to the element
        const middleX = rect.width / 3;
        return x - middleX;
      }

      function handleMouseMove(e) {
        const deltaX = getMouseDirection(e, container);
        // Move text left or right based on mouse movement
        // alert(deltaX / 13)
        console.log(deltaX);

        if (text) {
          container.style.transition = "all 0.9s ease-in";
          text.style.position = "absolute";
          text.style.top = "70.5%";
          text.style.left = "50%";
          imageMove.style.position = "absolute";
          imageMove.style.top = "71%";
          imageMove.style.left = "50%";
          text.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) translateX(${-(
            deltaX / 40
          )}px)`; // Adjust movement strength as needed
          imageMove.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) translateX(${
            deltaX / 40
          }px)`;
        }
      }

      function handleMouseLeave() {
        // Reset text position on mouse leave
        if (text) {
          text.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%)`;
          imageMove.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%)`;
          container.style.transition = "all 0.9s ease-out";
        }
      }

      container.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      container.addEventListener("mouseleave", handleMouseLeave);

      return () => {
        container.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        container.removeEventListener("mouseleave", handleMouseLeave);
      };
    }, 3300);
  }, []);

  return (
    <section
      data-w-id="bbb1681c-62a0-7375-a529-1c7bec5a4a0e"
      className="section  pt-[30px]"
      ref={containerRef}
      style={{ transition: "all 0.8 ease-in-out" }}
    >
      <div className="container no-paddings " id="container">
        <div className="hero-section">
          <div className="hero-section-text-holder transition-all ease-in-out duration-500">
            <div className="hero-section-sticky">
              <div className="hero-sticky-holder" id="transformatedText">
                <div className="hero-text-holder" ref={textRef}>
                  <div
                    className="hero-text-wrapper _01"
                    id="makeEffectInto-left-Text"
                  >
                    <div
                      className="hero-text transition-all ease-in-out duration-500"
                      id="meedtextone"
                    >
                      Meet
                    </div>
                    <div className="hero-text-blur">Meet</div>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    className="hero-text-wrapper _02"
                    id="makeEffectInto-right-Text"
                  >
                    <div
                      className="hero-text _02  transition-all ease-in-out duration-500"
                      id="meedtextone2"
                    >
                      Black
                    </div>
                    <div className="hero-text-blur ">Black</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div
              className="iphone-holder"
              id="hiddenImageComesFromDown"
              ref={imagemove}
            >
              <img
                src="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefb47917c0cfa0943fc97_iPhone%2014%20Pro%20%E2%80%93%20Space%20Black.webp"
                loading="lazy"
                sizes="(max-width: 767px) 196.6796875px, 295.015625px"
                srcSet="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefb47917c0cfa0943fc97_iPhone%2014%20Pro%20%E2%80%93%20Space%20Black-p-500.webp 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefb47917c0cfa0943fc97_iPhone%2014%20Pro%20%E2%80%93%20Space%20Black.webp 800w"
                alt=""
                id="imageId-forRemove-hiddhen"
                className="iphone-image hidden"
              />
              <div className="iphone-screen">
                <img
                  src="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefd2632bfdbf4073fa431_Hero%20Iphone%20Image.webp"
                  loading="lazy"
                  alt=""
                  sizes="(max-width: 479px) 80vw, 267.875px"
                  srcSet="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefd2632bfdbf4073fa431_Hero%20Iphone%20Image-p-500.webp 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63aefd2632bfdbf4073fa431_Hero%20Iphone%20Image.webp 729w"
                  className="iphone-screen-image hidden"
                  id="imageId-forRemove-hiddhen2"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="iphone-drop-shadow"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="hero-section-paragraph-holder">
            <div className="hero-paragraph-holder" id="onScrollPosition">
              <p>
                Effortlessly track and manage your time with Black. Customizable
                reports, invoicing, and integrations make it the perfect tool
                for freelancers and professionals.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="from-wra-er">
              <div className="form-block w-form">
                <form
                  id="email-form"
                  name="email-form"
                  data-name="Email Form"
                  method="get"
                  data-wf-page-id="63aee5793ca698e95ffe7f77"
                  data-wf-element-id="5ea415ca-a921-34a0-1f6c-2725653f3203"
                  aria-label="Email Form"
                >
                  <div className="from-holder">
                    <input
                      className="text-field-form w-input"
                      maxLength="256"
                      name="email-2"
                      data-name="Email 2"
                      placeholder="Enter Your Email"
                      type="email"
                      id="email-2"
                      required=""
                    />
                    <input
                      type="submit"
                      data-wait="Please wait..."
                      className="button from w-button"
                      value="Start Free Trial"
                    />
                  </div>
                </form>
                <div
                  className="success-message w-form-done"
                  tabIndex="-1"
                  role="region"
                  aria-label="Email Form success"
                >
                  <div>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</div>
                </div>
                <div
                  className="error-message w-form-fail"
                  tabIndex="-1"
                  role="region"
                  aria-label="Email Form failure"
                >
                  <div>
                    Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="logo-grid-holder" id="imageTransform">
          <div className="w-layout-grid logo-grid">
            <div
              id="w-node-f078fdf9-afcd-dd23-e056-d7d58c77dcd8-5ffe7f77"
              className="logo-small-container"
            >
              <img
                src="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63af02dceb85a1104ee0c8f5_Logo01.svg"
                loading="lazy"
                alt=""
                className="logo-small"
              />
            </div>
            <div
              id="w-node-f078fdf9-afcd-dd23-e056-d7d58c77dcda-5ffe7f77"
              className="logo-small-container"
            >
              <img
                src="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63af02dc67bbed2fe0724574_Logo02.svg"
                loading="lazy"
                alt=""
                className="logo-small"
              />
            </div>
            <div
              id="w-node-f078fdf9-afcd-dd23-e056-d7d58c77dcdc-5ffe7f77"
              className="logo-small-container"
            >
              <img
                src="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63af02dccee58c6ac31a1ff8_Logo03.svg"
                loading="lazy"
                alt=""
                className="logo-small"
              />
            </div>
            <div
              id="w-node-f078fdf9-afcd-dd23-e056-d7d58c77dcde-5ffe7f77"
              className="logo-small-container"
            >
              <img
                src="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63af02dc892ff685649d683b_Logo04.svg"
                loading="lazy"
                alt=""
                className="logo-small"
              />
            </div>
            <div
              id="w-node-f078fdf9-afcd-dd23-e056-d7d58c77dce0-5ffe7f77"
              className="logo-small-container"
            >
              <img
                src="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63af02dc3ca6982d5900e42a_Logo05.svg"
                loading="lazy"
                alt=""
                className="logo-small"
              />
            </div>
            <div
              id="w-node-f078fdf9-afcd-dd23-e056-d7d58c77dce2-5ffe7f77"
              className="logo-small-container"
            >
              <img
                src="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63af02dc0e332ae5dc9fe5e4_Logo06.svg"
                loading="lazy"
                alt=""
                className="logo-small"
              />
            </div>
            <div
              id="w-node-f078fdf9-afcd-dd23-e056-d7d58c77dce4-5ffe7f77"
              className="logo-small-container"
            >
              <img
                src="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63af02dcf706a1a426eb3608_Logo07.svg"
                loading="lazy"
                alt=""
                className="logo-small"
              />
            </div>
            <div
              id="w-node-f078fdf9-afcd-dd23-e056-d7d58c77dce6-5ffe7f77"
              className="logo-small-container"
            >
              <img
                src="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63af02dc7013f86c8f8ee7f0_Logo08.svg"
                loading="lazy"
                alt=""
                className="logo-small"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="fade-in-move-on-scroll">
            <p>Trusted by Top-tier product campanies</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Hero;

